# Azure Availability Zone ARM Config

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create an ARM template which deploys a VM to a specified zone, however I keep getting the following error. Not sure why, I've checked online and followed the other examples, but still stuck.

The code for the zone template

```
   "zone": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Zone number for the virtual machine"
      }
    },
```

The Parameter file is:

```
"zone": {
  "value": "2"
},
```

But the error I get is:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 10:11:08 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template parse failed: 'Error converting value "2" to type 'System.String[]'. 
Path ''.'.
At line:7 char:1
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I have tried using the zone as an array and integer, but neither seem to work.

Thanks in advance :)

############ Edit
Parameter file

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vmName": {
      "value": "vm2002"
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "localadmin"
    },
    "adminPasswordOrKey": {
      "value": "P@ssword1234"
    },
    "ubuntuOSVersion": {
      "value": "18.04-LTS"
    },
    "VmSize": {
      "value": "Standard_d2-v4"
    },
    "networkName": {
      "value": "tt-vnet"
    },
    "networkResourceGroup": {
      "value": "deployrg3"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "value": "tt-sub1"
    },
    "zone": {
      "value": [
        "2"
      ]
    },
    "diskCount": {
      "value": 2
    },
    "diskSize": {
      "value": [
        "32"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Template File

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "linuxvm",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of you Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "authenticationType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "password",
      "allowedValues": [
        "sshPublicKey",
        "password"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Type of authentication to use on the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
      }
    },
    "adminPasswordOrKey": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "SSH Key or password for the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
      }
    },
    "ubuntuOSVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "18.04-LTS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "12.04.5-LTS",
        "14.04.5-LTS",
        "16.04.0-LTS",
        "18.04-LTS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Ubuntu version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Ubuntu version."
      }
    },
    "VmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_B2s",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The size of the VM"
      }
    },
    "networkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "networkResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "zone": {
      "type": "array"
      "defaultValue": "1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Zone number for the virtual machine"
      }
    },
    "diskCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1
    },
    "diskSize": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "cnt": "[Parameters('diskCount')]",
    "osDiskType": "Premium_LRS",
    "VNetID": "[resourceId(Parameters('networkResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', Parameters('networkname'))]",
    "SubnetRef": "[concat(variables('VNetID'), '/subnets/', Parameters('subnetName'))]",
    "networkInterfaceName": "[concat(Parameters('VMName'), '-nic1')]",
    "linuxConfiguration": {
      "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
      "ssh": {
        "publicKeys": [
          {
            "path": "[concat('/home/', parameters('adminUsername'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
            "keyData": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "name": "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              },
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]"
      ],
      "zones": "[parameters('zone')]",
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('VmSize')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "fromImage",
            "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "[variables('osDiskType')]"
            },
            "copy": [
              {
                "name": "datadisks",
                "count": "[variables('cnt')]",
                "input": {
                  "name": "[concat(Parameters('VMName'), '-dataDisk', add(copyIndex('datadisks'), 1))]",
                  "createOption": "Empty",
                  "diskSizeGB": "[Parameters('diskSize')[copyIndex('datadisks')]]",
                  "caching": "None",
                  "lun": "[copyIndex('datadisks')]"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "Canonical",
            "offer": "UbuntuServer",
            "sku": "[parameters('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]",
          "linuxConfiguration": "[if(equals(parameters('authenticationType'), 'password'), json('null'), variables('linuxConfiguration'))]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which template API version do you refer to? If you are using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2020-12-01/virtualmachines?tabs=json),  The zones should be an array  `"zones": [
    "string"
  ],` So you may use the parameter like `"zone": {
  "value": ["2"]
},`

Comment: @NancyXiong thanks for the quick response. The  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01", however in a string, or array or integer I still get errors.

Comment: @NancyXiong as an array at line '126' and column '9'. 'The language 
expression property array index '1' is out of bounds.' (Code:InvalidTemplate) :(

Comment: Can you post the bit of the ARM template where you're *using* the ```zone``` parameter? It's possible you're just referring to it incorrectly. For example in https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.compute/vm-simple-zones/azuredeploy.json the parameter is *used* as follows: ```"zones": [ "[parameters('zone')]" ],``` which wraps your parameter value into an array. You *might* just have something like this in your ARM template instead: ```"zones": "[parameters('zone')]",``` which would cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: @nan https://pastebin.com/embed_js/QDjrWEtA

Comment: @NancyXiong Code has been uploaded, apologies for the delay

Comment: According to your code, the parameter zone is array, you can use `"zone": {
  "value": ["2"]
},` in your parameter file.

Comment: @NancyXiong I'm still getting error  `'The language 
expression property array index '1' is out of bounds.' (Code:InvalidTemplate)` using the parameter `     "zone": {
      "value": [
        "2"
      ]
    },`

Comment: You need to make sure the ```type```, ```defaultValue``` and ```allowedValues``` are all consistent in your parameter definition in the template file, *and* make sure the parameter value in the parameters file matches the specified type *and* the type has to valid at the point where you're using it in the ARM template. If they aren't *all* consistent you're going to get various errors about type mismatches.

Comment: Can you please post *in your question* (i.e. not an external link in comments) an extract of all three of these (i) the ```zone``` parameter definition the arm template (ii) the ```zone``` parameter value assignment in the parameters file (iii) a short extract of any parts of the ARM template that reference the ```zone``` parameter. We can then help you determine if there's a type mismatch somewhere.

Comment: @mclayton Thanks, I'll edit the question. I'm just using dummy values so I'll post both template and parameter file.

Comment: @mclayton have you had a chance to look at the templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message *The language  expression property array index '1' is out of bounds.* is a bit misleading. After my validation. The main problem is using "copy" in `dataDisks` property there.

When you define the parameter **diskCount** number as `2`, you should also define 2 matching elements in the parameter **diskSize** array. Also, I change to define the paramater **zone** type to `string` type.

Here is the working sample:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "linuxvm",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of you Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "authenticationType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "password",
      "allowedValues": [
        "sshPublicKey",
        "password"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Type of authentication to use on the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
      }
    },
    "adminPasswordOrKey": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "SSH Key or password for the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
      }
    },
    "ubuntuOSVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "18.04-LTS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "12.04.5-LTS",
        "14.04.5-LTS",
        "16.04.0-LTS",
        "18.04-LTS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Ubuntu version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Ubuntu version."
      }
    },
    "VmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_B2s",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The size of the VM"
      }
    },
    "networkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "networkResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "zone": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Zone number for the virtual machine"
      }
    }
    ,
    "diskCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1
    },
    "diskSize": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "cnt": "[Parameters('diskCount')]",
    "osDiskType": "Premium_LRS",
    "VNetID": "[resourceId(Parameters('networkResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', Parameters('networkname'))]",
    "SubnetRef": "[concat(variables('VNetID'), '/subnets/', Parameters('subnetName'))]",
    "networkInterfaceName": "[concat(Parameters('VMName'), '-nic1')]",
    "linuxConfiguration": {
      "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
      "ssh": {
        "publicKeys": [
          {
            "path": "[concat('/home/', parameters('adminUsername'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
            "keyData": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "name": "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              },
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]"
      ],
      "zones": [
          "[parameters('zone')]"
          ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('VmSize')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {

          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "Canonical",
            "offer": "UbuntuServer",
            "sku": "[parameters('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "fromImage",
            "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "[variables('osDiskType')]"
            }
          },

            "copy": [

                {
                "name": "dataDisks",
                "count": "[variables('cnt')]",
                "input": {
                  "name": "[concat(Parameters('VMName'), '-dataDisk', add(copyIndex('dataDisks'), 1))]",
                  "createOption": "Empty",
                  "diskSizeGB": "[Parameters('diskSize')[copyIndex('dataDisks')]]",
                  "caching": "None",
                  "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]"
                }
              }

            ]

        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]",
          "linuxConfiguration": "[if(equals(parameters('authenticationType'), 'password'), json('null'), variables('linuxConfiguration'))]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Parameters:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "vmName": {
        "value": "vm2002"
      },
      "adminUsername": {
        "value": "localadmin"
      },
      "adminPasswordOrKey": {
        "value": "Password"
      },
      "ubuntuOSVersion": {
        "value": "18.04-LTS"
      },
    //   "VmSize": {
    //     "value": "Standard_B1s"
    //   },
      "networkName": {
        "value": "vvvv"
      },
      "networkResourceGroup": {
        "value": "nancyarm"
      },
      "subnetName": {
        "value": "default"
      },
      "zone": {
        "value": "2"      
      },
      "diskCount": {
        "value": 2
      },
      "diskSize": {
        "value": [32,64]
      }
    }
  }
```